# React Native: Expo's Fast Refresh feature only works in App.js properly in Expo GO mobile app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have the following folder structure

my-app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ src/
│  ├─ RepositoryItem.jsx
│  ├─ RepositoryList.jsx
│  ├─ Main.jsx
├─ package.json
├─ README.md
├─ App.js

RepositoryList and RepositoryItem are imported into Main.jsx. Main.jsx imported into App.js

If I modify the code in App.js or Main.js, and save it. The Expo GO app immediately shows the changes.

If I modify RepositoryList.jsx or RepositoryItem.jsx components and save, fast refresh happens, but the changes are not shown. Only if i manually reload the app.

If I modify RepositoryList.jsx component AND Main.jsx. The changes in Main.jsx are shown immediately, bit the changes in RepositoryList.jsx only after a manual reload.

Also if I change RepositoryItem or RepositoryList... "Refreshing... Using Fast Refresh shows" but the changes are not reflected in the app

I tried it with a phone and a tablet, problem is present on both devices.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using JSX files (RepositoryItem.jsx; RepositoryList.jsx; Main.jsx).
Have you tried changing the extension just to JS? (Javascript)
I.e: RepositoryItem.js

Answer (score 0):

Fast Refresh works in files that are nested in subfolders like `RepositoryList.js` and `RepositoryItem.js`.

Why it didn't refresh for me is because in `RepositoryList` I return a `FlatList` component, and inside of that the `renderItem` is the `RepositoryItem`. Like so:

```
return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
            data={repositories}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
            renderItem={RepositoryItem}
        />
    </View>
);
```

Now the question is: Why does Fast Refresh not work if I change `RepositoryItem`, which is the `renderItem` attribute of `FlatList`?

Comment: Suggestions or queries regarding asked questions must be maintained in the comment section/question post. Answer post meant for solving the question only.